# Vuejs tab doesn't show up anymore but was working before

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, devtools

Since this morning I can't see the Vue tab in Chrome dev tools.
The console now shows this message:

```
Download the Vue Devtools for a better development experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
```

How do I get the Vue tab back?

Comment: Open `chrome://extensions/` in Chrome, check what version of the Vue Devtools extension you are using. Then edit your question to include both the version of Vue Devtools and the verison of Chrome.

Comment: when i clicked on my extensions I actually saw that my vue devtools wasn't  surprisingly enabled anymore but instead I could see "reload". same for my chrome version that had to be updated. Thank you so much you fixed my problem